# What is the term for saying something out loud that you wish for

Tags: phrase-requests

I remember there is a term/saying for accidentally speaking something out loud about what you secretly wish for. For example: you like someone, but you aren't awared of it, but then accidentally say it out loud in a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for: **Freudian slip**. Thanks.

Per Wikipedia,

> In psychoanalysis, a [Freudian slip](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip), also called parapraxis, is an
> error in speech, memory, or physical action that occurs due to the
> interference of an unconscious subdued wish or internal train of
> thought. Classical examples involve slips of the tongue, but
> psychoanalytic theory also embraces misreadings, mishearings,
> mistypings, temporary forgettings, and the mislaying and losing of
> objects.